# How we can use external site URL in moodle redirect function?

Tags: php, moodle

I am trying to use a external site URL say www.google.ca specified in the block config settings in moodle redirect function. It seems like moodle always prep-pends the current directory path with that url, what is the work around for that? I also, tried using header(), but when I specify in header the hardcoded url it works, when it is grabbed from config settings it doesn't.

In short, I want to redirect to a certain page(outside my moodle domain) using moodle redirect function.How this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site url in the config should start with http:// otherwise moodle thinks its relative